# What's the difference between jQuery.fn.empty() and jQuery.fn.html('')?

Tags: jquery

Is there any difference between

```
$("#header").empty()
```

and

```
$("#header").html('')
```

?

Also, which should I use? `$("#header").empty()` is more readable, but how could anything be faster than `$("#header").html('')`?

Comment: ``.empty()`` is **much faster**: http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-html/17

Comment: Also non jQuery quickie ... `$("#header").get(0).innerHTML = "";` ...but  jQuery's empty seems to be even much faster than that ...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the two. Use `.empty()` since it is shorter (more terse) and more readable.

Don't worry about the performance difference. Remember, jQuery isn't used because it *runs* faster than vanilla JavaScript — it's used because it's *written* faster. Developer time is worth far more than processor time.

There's already a jsPerf to compare the relative performance: http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-html. **Every single test case shows that `.empty()` is faster.**

---

Straight from the jQuery source:

```
empty: function() {
    for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
            jQuery.cleanData( elem.getElementsByTagName("*") );
        }

        // Remove any remaining nodes
        while ( elem.firstChild ) {
            elem.removeChild( elem.firstChild );
        }
    }

    return this;
},

html: function( value ) {
    if ( value === undefined ) {
        return this[0] && this[0].nodeType === 1 ?
            this[0].innerHTML.replace(rinlinejQuery, "") :
            null;

    // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
    } else if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnocache.test( value ) &&
        (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test( value )) &&
        !wrapMap[ (rtagName.exec( value ) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase() ] ) {

        value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

        try {
            for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                if ( this[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
                    jQuery.cleanData( this[i].getElementsByTagName("*") );
                    this[i].innerHTML = value;
                }
            }

        // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
        } catch(e) {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }

    } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( value ) ) {
        this.each(function(i){
            var self = jQuery( this );

            self.html( value.call(this, i, self.html()) );
        });

    } else {
        this.empty().append( value );
    }

    return this;
},
```

`.empty()` doesn't have to deal with checking the different possible argument types; it can get right down to chucking out DOM elements.

Comment: "Developer time is worth far more than processor time." - until the app runs visibly slow :)

Comment: That's user time, not processor time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the actual source code for $().empty

```
function() {
    for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
            jQuery.cleanData( elem.getElementsByTagName("*") );
        }

        // Remove any remaining nodes
        while ( elem.firstChild ) {
            elem.removeChild( elem.firstChild );
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

As you can see it's a bit more involved than `.html('')` but as Matt suggests jQuery speeds up development not necessarily execution. As the comments in the code suggest there are advantages to using `.empty` vs `.html` in terms of cleaning up the environment once DOM nodes are removed etc