# jQuery empty() vs text('')

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

Is there any different between

`$(element).empty()` and `$(element).text('');`

Which one is better?

Comment: `empty()` will get rid of HTML and Text, while `text('')` will get rid of text. they are 2 different things. So it depends on what you need

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723789/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-fn-empty-and-jquery-fn-html

Comment: Just a guess at the internals, clearing something should be faster than assigning it to an empty string. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5723797/485048) proves my assumption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Result is the same, but if we look at jQuery [text](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.text) method implementation:

```
text: function (value) {
    return jQuery.access(this, function (value) {
        return value === undefined
            ? jQuery.text(this)
            : this.empty().append((this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode(value));
    }, null, value, arguments.length);
},
```

we will see that `$(element).text('');` will actually use `.empty` internally. Hence latter is a little faster.

Also from semantic point of view if you want to *empty* some node you should definetely use `.empty` method, not `text`.

Comment: Took the initiative to read the code after I posted the question.. Lazy me