# jQuery remove selector content from a string

Tags: jquery, removechild, dom-manipulation

My javascript html string is:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="innercontent">
        <div>this should be removed</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

My wanted result is:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="asd"></div>
    <div id="innercontent">
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I try with several approaches that I found on SO, but all approaches removed also #innercontent element:

```
console.log($('#innercontent', content).remove().end().html());
```

I try with:

```
console.log($('#innercontent', content).children().remove().end().html());
```

but this is not giving me expected result. It returns empty string.

I need in separately string #innercontent html and html without #innercontent content. How? 
I can get #innercontent content with `$('#innercontent', content).html()`, but how can I remove this html from whole content?

I also try with string.replace, but it doesn't work (doesn't replace anything):

```
content = content.replace($('#innercontent', content).html(), "");
```

**EDITED:**

My content object is my javascript html string.

**EDITED 2**
Obviously I should write that I don't have this html in the DOM (body) or somewhere else. I get it from ajax. So empty is not the solution I am looking for.
I need innercontent and content string for further manipulation and then I append them to the DOM to different parents.

Comment: what is `content` object ? You don't show it being defined. WHen you have an ID you don't even need a context like your `content`, just use ID selector ...unless you have duplicated ID's in page which is a whole different scenario

Comment: is that string in the DOM? If it's in the DOM it's not usually referred to as a string. If it's not in the DOM( page) then need to see where it comes from

Comment: No it is the string from AJAX as I explain in my original(edited) post.

Comment: That obviously wasn't clear to anyone as all the answers assumed it was in the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For HTML data  received via ajax**

To remove elements from data received using ajax you wrap the html string received in `$()` and then can use jQuery methods as if it was in the DOM.

```
$.get('some/path/to/server/', function( data){
   /* create jQuery object with new html*/
   var $content = $(data);
   /* empty content section by traversing from outer root*/
   $content.find('#innercontent').empty();
   /* insert new content object in DOM*/
   $('#someDivInDOM').append( $content);
});
```

Since no ajax was shown in question I used shortcut `$.get`. The princibles are the same if using low level `$.ajax` just perform same tasks in the `success` or `done` callback

<kbd>**[WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Cv1j2JNCRvBm5vulUmW?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Don't know why I never try this. I am embarrassed, because I though it must exists in the DOM. Thanks. I slightly edited your post.

Comment: I rejected your edit as it doesn't match the html in the question and also had a needless loop in it. remember that questions live here for years, so mismatch bewteen answer and question causes confusion

Comment: Don't feel bad... without knowing that you can do this outside the DOM it wouldn;t necessarily be intuitive

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) function:

```js
var remove = function() {
  $('#innercontent').empty();
}

$('#empty').click(function() {
  remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="innercontent">
        <div>this should be removed</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>

<span id="empty" style="font-weight:bold;color:red;cursor:pointer">click to empty!</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the content of a div by using:

```
$('#innercontent').html('');
```

or by using:

```
$('#innercontent').empty();
```

For differences bewteen them in performance I recommend you to read the following:

[What's the difference between jQuery.fn.empty() and jQuery.fn.html('')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723789/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-fn-empty-and-jquery-fn-html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#innercontent').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the empty method.

```
$('#innercontent').empty();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cg0cy4jj/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.empty()` Method of jquery to remove all children of a selected element.

```
$('#innercontent').empty();
```

Use the `.html('')` Method of jquery to set is innerHtml to empty string.

```
$('#innercontent').html('');
```

Both will give you same results visually.