# Ajax removing all childelemets and readding the updated values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an ajax request to post a new message to a database. The page auto loads elements from the database onload. I want to delete the elements and re-add them when a user makes a post to add the current most post to the top of the list and its not working. I'm not sure why. There is no console error but it doesn't remove them.

onload ajax call

```
                            $.ajax({
                            url : "/getposts/", 
                            type : "POST",
                            dataType: "json", 
                            data : {
                                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                                },
                                success : function(json) {
                                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (json['message']);
                                    for (var index = 0; index < json['user_posts'].length; index++) { 
                                        var div_make_badassness = document.createElement('div');
                                        div_make_badassness.id = json['user_posts'][index][3];
                                        document.getElementById('post_section').appendChild(div_make_badassness);
                                        document.getElementById(json['user_posts'][index][3]).innerHTML = "<div id=" + json['user_posts'][index][3] + ">" + "Title:" + json['user_posts'][index][1] + "<br>" + json['user_posts'][index][0] + " Chomps: " + json['user_posts'][index][2] + "</div>" ;
                                    }

                                },
                                error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Request Failed.";
                                }

                        });
```

on submit ajax call

```
                        $.ajax({
                            url : "/makepost/", 
                            type : "POST",
                            dataType: "json", 
                            data : {
                                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                                username: username,
                                post_title: post_title,
                                post_text: post_text,
                                },
                                success : function(json) {
                                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (json['message']);

                                     var post_section = document.getElementById("post_section");

                                     for (var index = 0; index < post_section.length; index++) {
                                        post_section.removeChild(post_section.childNodes[index]);
                                     }
```

div tag

```
 <div id ='post_section'>

 </div>
                                    for (var index = 0; index < json['user_posts'].length; index++) { 

                                        console.log(json['user_posts'][index][3] + json['user_posts'][index][1] + json['user_posts'][index][2]);
                                        var div_make_badassness = document.createElement('div');
                                        div_make_badassness.id = json['user_posts'][index][3];
                                        document.getElementById('post_section').appendChild(div_make_badassness);
                                        document.getElementById(json['user_posts'][index][3]).innerHTML = "<div id=" + json['user_posts'][index][3] + ">" + "Title:" + json['user_posts'][index][1] + "<br>" + json['user_posts'][index][0] + " Chomps: " + json['user_posts'][index][2] + "</div>" ;
                                    }
```

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: @elf maybe but its dynamic data from a django request being returned as a json list. I'm not really sure how to do that in a fiddle. sorry. I could try but it would take me like an hour.

Comment: no need. use some sample data. make one or two records thats enuf

Comment: @elf ok let me set it up today. and Ill comment you when I do.

Comment: Side note, you're mixing jQuery and non-jQuery approaches. For instance, `document.getElementById('post_section')` in jQuery is written `$('#post_section')` and `x.innerHTML = y` in jQuery is `x.html(y)`. Also, be super-careful with innerHTML because it can leave you wide open to XSS. It's almost never a good idea to set raw HTML when doing DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using jQuery, I'll just do it in jQuery.

```
// Will remove any html in "post_section" and add in the new posts
function updatePostSection(user_posts) {
  var post_section = $('#post_section');
  post_section.html(''); // Remove all html contents inside

  for(var i = 0; i < user_posts.length; i++) {
    var div = $('<div>');
    div.attr('id', user_posts[i][3]);
    div.html("Title:" + user_posts[i][1]);
    post_section.append(div);
  }
}
```

In the success ajax function you can do something like...

```
// ...
success : function(json) {
  updatePostSection(json['user_posts']);
},
// ...
```

Then you should be able to use it for both your `getposts` and `makepost` ajax calls assuming the json is the same structure.

**Update:** There are ways to optimize this so you're only writing to the dom once, but this is just an example.

Comment: The recommended way to empty an element in jQuery is `post_section.empty()`.

Comment: Yes, .empty() is ideal, I was trying to use fewer functions for easy of understanding. [More on .empty() vs .html('')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723789/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-fn-empty-and-jquery-fn-html)